# Unexpected border found on the random left side of a column in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I create a row with 24 columns inside. I didn't put gutter and border between the cell so each column is stacked with one another. However, in Chrome browser, I found a weird thing. There are borders on the random left side of a column.
Chrome : 
[image]

Firefox : 
[image]

Could anyone explain to me what condition is this ? Thanks

Additional Information :

- A column has `display:inline-block`, `margin-right:-4px`, `position:relative`, and `vertical-align:top`
- A row has 100% width

Comment: Can you share your `html` and `css` code?

Comment: @jiff I think the problem is the browser, not the html and css. Maybe someone has seen this before.

Comment: No I would not say it's `html` issue or else, I want see a live demo and test it on `chrome` and `fire fox` for compare. or at least find a trick to remove this on chrome. Also, sometimes chrome will better display html issue than FF. and i see negative margin on your `css` it's not good!

Comment: Using the information provided. the issue can not be reproduced. [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/z123oqLy/). Ergo, the problem lies elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `inline-block` for elements extra white spaces will be added due to the spaces between the HTML tags as line breaks and tabs count as space.

This white space is determined by the font of it's parent container.
Setting `margin-right: -4px` is improper to use, as it might be either 3x or 5px depending on the type of font used.

[Here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MyErMO) is an example of how `font-size` affects the space between the elements.

A more elegant solution to fight these spaces would be to float your elements and not used inline-blocks at all or you could use flexbox.

Comment: Setting the font-size of the parent container to 0 and the children elements back to their normal size will also remove the issue.

Comment: @KrisD I want to told you that previously that problem hadn't emerged in Chrome. It works well. But for other time, I got this problem immediately. Are there any explanation to this ?

Comment: @tayvano - the only drawback with your approach is when using ems for font sizing as the children will also have zero size since ems cascade.

Comment: Excellent point. Rems or pixels should be used if you take this approach. Personally, I find floating to be the least "hacky"  way. Flexbox  is up there as well as soon as Internet Explorer stops existing.

Comment: @BillyHalim - these gaps can be seen if the font changes or if you resize the viewport. I cannot identify what might be the problem as I am not sure what changes you have made from when it worked to when it stopped working, but some changes might have occurred that caused this.

Comment: @KrisD By the way, it already worked because of a simple silly mistake. Just because my browser has zoom of 90%. Thanks by the way.